# Indication of overfitting

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard

I'm training an image recognition model using Inception and transfer learning, based on the Tensorflow of Poets tutorial.

I have it running for 500k steps, looking to see the optimum number of steps before overtraining strats. The below tensorboard image displays my training accuracy steadily rising but validation accuracy has plateaued around 70K steps. My understanding was validation accuracy would start going down when it started overtraining.

What would be my optimum number of steps in the below chart? 70k steps or 260k?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is crystal clear that you are overfitting your model. To solve the overfitting problem there are several solutions:

1) Early stopping.

2) Regularization.

3) Reducing your model VC dimension by reducing the number of layers or number of units per layer.

4) Augmenting your dataset.

5) Applying transfer learning.

For your case, you can try early stopping. The best number of iterations according to your graph is 60K.